# 600GB Normalizing from CSV or from Database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-migration

I am just now starting to normalize a 600GB database. We are moving it of Amazon RDS using sqldump to our local server (64GB RAM and 1,5TB SSD) where we will host the new normalized database.

The database consist of a single table that we are going to brake up into 4 different tables to remove all redundant data.

My question is: What is likely to be the best process?

1. Restoring all of the 600GB to a local temporary database and having a porting script query data from there and inserting into the new normalized structure.
2. Downloading a CSV dump instead of a .sql file and write a porting script that reads the CSV and feeds the date into the new normalized structure?

Or

3. Is there a better way for re-factoring a database of that size?

For both solutions am tinging of building a caching script to deal with redundant foreign key look-up, but maybe mysql can handle that for be somehow?

Comment: For normalizing you need to factor out tables by performing GROUP BY aggregations. If you only have CSV and not a MySQL database you will have trouble doing those aggregations. How would you perform them?

Comment: If was going with the CSV I was thinking of just doing row by row insert querys via a script and ignoring all duplicated data.

But I'm probably missing something big because I see how using GROUP BY would be helpful when creating and populating the new tables with the normalized data. But I still can't see a way to "convert" the redundant date in the main "item field" to the corespondent id key's without iterating and running SQL inserts. Are there a better way ?
Something like this but using a sub-query? 
UPDATE t1 SET col1 = find_key_of(col1);

Comment: I'm a SQL Server guy and my MySql knowledge is exceeded here. In SQL Server I'd pull everything into a DB for certain. Processing 600GB of data row-by-row with an external driver application is going to take some time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually easier and faster to work solely in a SQL database than with external files as well.

It gives you better performance, and also lets you easily keep the original column types if that's what you want to do.  You might have to be quite careful about data types if you go via CSV, which is essentially just text.

So I'd prefer option 1, preferably testing the scripts on an extract of the original table that holds only a small fraction of the original records.

Although the space taken by the new database will be less, hopefully, than in the unnormalised one, if your 1.5 TB SSD is the only attached storage, it's going to be fairly full by the time the conversion is complete, and before you delete the original.  Log files might be very large, depending on how you do it.  You might want to stick a few extra TB of HDD in there temporarily.

If that's an issue, would doing the conversion entirely in the remote machine be feasible?  Then you'd only need to download the converted database to the local server.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any input on my comment above? When I have all the data normalized in the new tables, what is the best way to go through the the main table and replacing redundant data with there new corresponding id's? Morphing the existing data, or create a new field?